# Scale height of FigureCanvas with app window size?

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt

So I'm building a GUI with PyQt. One of the rows in my QVBoxLayout is a FigureCanvas that I'm using for plotting. I can't figure out how to scale the height of the canvas with the app window. The two screenshots show how the canvas height doesn't really change even though I maxed out the app window. Below is the code for the FigureCanvas widget. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've tried setSizePolicy, setContentsMargins, stretches, but I don't think I understand them enough to be using them correctly.

```
class InteractivePlotWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(InteractivePlotWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        # Create a Figure and a FigureCanvas
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(
            tight_layout=True,
            facecolor='none',edgecolor='k'
        )
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.canvas.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        self.canvas.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.canvas.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;")
        self.canvas.draw()

        # Create a NavigationToolbar for interactivity
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

        # Create a layout and add the canvas and toolbar to it
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    
        # initial properties
        self.ax.set_axis_off()
        self.ax.set_facecolor('none')
    
        # init
        self.image = None
        self.puzzle = None

    def update_plot(self, image, alpha, bound_color):
        # Create a simple example plot
        self.ax.clear()
        self.image = self.ax.imshow(image, alpha=alpha)
        self.ax.set_xlim([0,image.width])
        self.ax.set_ylim([0,image.height])
        self.ax.set_axis_off()
        self.ax.set_facecolor('none')
        self.ax.axis("tight")
        self.ax.set_aspect('equal')
        # Draw the plot on the canvas
        self.canvas.draw()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use the [`stretch` parameter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addWidget) when you add the canvas widget : `self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas, 1)`.

Comment: Post a [mre] including code on the layout of the window.